# iptables redirect to 80 but origin port is still available

Tags: iptables, node.js, port-80

I've got a node.js process running at port 9500.

I'm using iptables to redirect 80 to 9500 so - `iptables -t nat -L` outputs:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 9500

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And `iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers` outputs:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:18001
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9500
6    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Everything is good *except* my node app is available at port 80 & 9500 - is there a way to have it only available at port 80? I've tried removing rule #5 but then I fail to get a connection.

Comment: what's the problem of having the service available also at port 9500? you could block with iptables access to port 9500 from the outside and allow from inside (for the redirect) if that bothers you (restrict rule 5).

Comment: From an SEO perspective, it's never a good idea to have web page accessible from two URLs (ports count). BUT - how would you implement the inside/outside? It sounds promising. I'm barely functional when it comes to iptables config.

Comment: regarding SEO I'm not sure how google would learn about the non-standard web port or if it would treat it as different content but you could use the same tactics for de-duplication like one entry in the robots.txt file to disallow indexing of non-standard port, permanent redirects etc

Comment: @stockholmux Either set your node.js application to listen port 80 or make it listen port 9500 on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Setting node.js to listen locally is cleaner, it won't expose port 9500 and you don't have to change any iptables rule: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_localaddress

Comment: I was really hoping for a solution within iptables. Seems like it should be possible.